# How to deserialize a protobuf packet from QUdpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, protocol-buffers

I am having trouble when I try to deserialize a protobuf packet when I receive it from a QUdpSocket.

My project structure is

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libs
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── vision
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── docs
│       │   └── requirements.txt
│       ├── external
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   ├── proto
│       │   │   ├── messages_robocup_ssl_detection.proto
│       │   │   ├── messages_robocup_ssl_geometry.proto
│       │   │   └── messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.proto
│       │   └── proto_compiled
│       │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_detection.pb.cc
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_detection.pb.h
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_geometry.pb.cc
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_geometry.pb.h
│       │       ├── messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.pb.cc
│       │       └── messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.pb.h
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   ├── vision.cpp
│       │   └── vision.hpp
│       └── tools
│           └── protobuf.bash
├── LICENSE
└── README.md
```

My vision.hpp file is

```
#ifndef VISION_H
#define VISION_H
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QObject>
#include "../external/proto_compiled/messages_robocup_ssl_wrapper.pb.h"

class Vision: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Vision(QObject *parent);
        void initSocket();
        int port_grsim = 10020;
        void processPendingDatagrams();
        SSL_WrapperPacket* packet = new SSL_WrapperPacket; // SSL_WrapperPacket is my class for the protobuf protocol

    private:
        QUdpSocket *socket=nullptr;
};

#endif
```

My vision.cpp file is

```
#include "vision.hpp"

Vision::Vision(QObject *parent) : 
    QObject(parent) {
}

void Vision::initSocket(){
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    bool result =  socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, this->port_grsim);
    if(result){
        qDebug() << "Socket PASS";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "Socket FAIL";
    }

    processPendingDatagrams();
    connect(socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &Vision::processPendingDatagrams);
}

void Vision::processPendingDatagrams(){
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 port;

    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        qDebug() << "in !";
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(),datagram.size(),&sender,&port);
        this->packet->ParseFromString(datagram.data());
        qDebug() <<"Message From :: " << sender.toString();
        qDebug() <<"Port From :: "<< port;
        qDebug() <<"Message :: " << packet;
    }
}
```

My main.cpp is

```
#include "vision/src/vision.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    auto visionPackets = new Vision(0);
    visionPackets->initSocket();
    while(true) visionPackets->processPendingDatagrams();
}
```

And the error I am having is (in english that could translate to undefined reference)

```
/usr/bin/ld: vision/src/libvision.a(vision.cpp.o): en la función `Vision::processPendingDatagrams()':
vision.cpp:(.text+0x441): referencia a `google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: vision/src/libvision.a(vision.cpp.o): en la función `SSL_WrapperPacket::SSL_WrapperPacket()':
vision.cpp:(.text._ZN17SSL_WrapperPacketC2Ev[_ZN17SSL_WrapperPacketC5Ev]+0x1d): referencia a `SSL_WrapperPacket::SSL_WrapperPacket(google::protobuf::Arena*)' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libs/CMakeFiles/sysmic.dir/build.make:116: libs/sysmic] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:166: libs/CMakeFiles/sysmic.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Could be a CMake error? I am very confused because I don't know how I could handle this error.

Comment: It seems you are not linking with the protobuf runtime library.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: The library is available in the same place where you obtained the `protoc` compiler's binary. You need to set up your project to link to that library. As to how, consult your build system's documentation.

Comment: Any reason you use your own socket instead of GRPC? I mean you already have a proto file so you can let GPRC do the IPC. Or is it because you need an UDP socket? (And if so what about packetloss?)

Comment: This is in the context of a robotic competition, I receive 22 packets/second about the robots positioning so it is not terrible if there are packet loss. I receive all the information by UDP Multicast, so I have to do it this way.